# I need two number side by side animate top to bottom and why need postions:absolute with animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I need two number side by side animate top to bottom But its not working. If i make postion:absolute in .f_circleG class its working but not side by side. Another question is why need postions:absolute with animation.Below is my HTML and CSS code.

```
<style type='text/css'>

  ul, ul li { list-style:none; display:inline; }

 .f_circleG{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#FFF;
  animation:f_fadeG 1.00s infinite;
 }

@-moz-keyframes f_fadeG {
   0%{ background-color:transparent; top:0px;}
   100%{ background-color:transparent; top:100%; }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>    
<div id="floatingCirclesG">
    <ul>
        <li  class="f_circleG">1</li>
        <li  class="f_circleG">2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/teZdz/

hope this will solve your problem

**html**

```
<div id="floatingCirclesG">
    <ul>
      <li class="f_circleG">1</li>
      <li class="f_circleG">2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
ul, ul li { list-style: none; display: inline; }

#floatingCirclesG { height: 200px; }

.f_circleG { position: relative; display: inline-block; -webkit-animation: f_fadeG 1.00s infinite; }

@-webkit-keyframes f_fadeG { 
0% {top:0px;}
100% {top:100%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanx for ans but Animation doesnt work even in your jsfiddle

Comment: sorry my mistek post wrong URL
chk it now on below URL in CHROME
http://jsfiddle.net/teZdz/

Answer (score 0):

Position:absoulte

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

Try this code

```
<ul>
<li  class="f_circleG">1</li>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
<li  class="f_circleG">2</li>
</ul>
```

If you dont add position:absolute in animation,the list items becomes static compared to the ancestor that is the list here and hence the animations will not work.

Comment: Thnx but dont want like this because i have more number so if is it possible by css i.e. marigin or padding ?